# "haut en couleurs" or "haut en couleur"

Tags: pluriel

> Trois ours tentent de s’intégrer à la vie de San Francisco, croisant des personnages tous plus **hauts en couleurs** les uns que les autres.

I wonder if "couleurs" shouldn't be used here in the singular instead?

> Trois ours tentent de s’intégrer à la vie de San Francisco, croisant des personnages tous plus **hauts en couleur** les uns que les autres.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, **hauts en couleur** is the correct form, but "haut en couleurs" is usual, especially in recent literature.